# Why is my for loop not working? Factorial program

Tags: javascript

I am currently doing a factorial script and I have finished it using a while loop. However, before resorting to said solution, I tried to use a for loop but didn't get the same result. It was like my for loop didn't exist and whenever I called the function with different values, it just took the first value of the accumulator (which is 1, you'll see in the code).

I am feeling like I made a dumb mistake and haven't realized what it is but I have run out of solution so if someone could give me hand, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
function factorial(num) {
  if (num === 0) {
    return 1; //Factorial of 0 is equal to 1.
  } else {
    var accumulator = 1;
    for (i = num; i < 1; i--)  { //continously decreases until reaching 1
      accumulator *= i; //redefines value multiplying it with the previous one.
    }
    return accumulator;
  }
}
```

Comment: `i > 1` instead of `i < 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for (i = num; i < 1; i--)` change it to `for (i = num; i > 1; i--)`. For loop runs until condition is true. In your case `i < 1` will evelute as `false`(if number is greter than 1) so excucuation doesn't go inside for loop.

> for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
>     
>      statement
>
> An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration. If this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed.
> If the expression evaluates to false, execution skips to the first expression following the for construct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My code is running perfectly now. Really complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

`i >= 1`?

```
for (i = num; i >= 1; i--)
....
```

Greater should work as well, because 1 does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, you want to create a loop which should run till the value of i is greater than 1, so that your **accumulator** variable can contain the product of all the number till 1.

But in your loop, you have mistakenly used '**<**' instead of '**>**', due to which **for** loop condition is never getting true and your loop is not executing.

replace your '**<**' in **for (i = num; i < 1; i--)** with '**>**'

Happy Coding

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for making me see the silly mistake I made :) Happy coding.